# What tags have the highest/lowest proportion of accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, tags, statistics

I'd be very interested to know how the probability of getting a good answer varies with programming languages or topics. Has anyone done any stats on the subject?

Comment: this sounds like a job for [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @psubsee2003 you mean job for rene... ;)

Comment: @Sha it only took him 2 years to get around to it :)

Answer (score 2):

I have crafted the query [Tags with their  proportion of accepted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/208339/tags-with-their-proportion-of-accepted-answers) that shows all tags with their accepted-posts count and total count per tag. The list is sorted descending for the percentage of those values.

#### Query

```
; with hightags as (
select row_number() over(order by count(*) desc) as row
      , t.tagname
      , count(*) as cnt
from tags t 
inner join posttags pt on pt.tagid = t.id
inner join posts p on pt.postid = p.id
where p.posttypeid = 1
and p.acceptedanswerid is not null
group by t.tagname
)
, tagcnt as (
select t.tagname
      , count(*) as cnt
from tags t 
inner join posttags pt on pt.tagid = t.id
inner join posts p on pt.postid = p.id
where p.posttypeid = 1
group by t.tagname
)
select hightags.row as row
       , hightags.tagname as [high]
       , hightags.cnt
        , tch.cnt as [all]
       , 100 * hightags.cnt / tch.cnt as [rate]
from hightags 
inner join tagcnt tch on tch.tagname = hightags.tagname
order by 100 * hightags.cnt / tch.cnt desc
```

#### Result

The first 10:

```
row   high                      cnt    all    rate 
----- ------------------------- ------ ------ ---- 
15823 petitparser               24     24     100  
21324 sinemacula                11     11     100  
22594 array-initialize          10     10     100  
22699 vmat                      10     10     100  
22790 business-model            9      9      100  
23083 rfc2396                   9      9      100  
23093 privileged-functions      9      9      100  
24168 paraffin                  8      8      100  
24553 cffeed                    7      7      100  
24653 production-code           7      7      100
```